# CSS: How can I position several elements stacked but also fixed at the bottom of the screen

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my own toastr alert  component and it's been going well using:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

The problem arises when more than one is displayed at the same time because I want them to stack when there is more than 1 alert. How can I accomplish this?

I'm also using bootstrap 4 if that's of any help.

Comment: Don’t position them all individually, but their common container element only …?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Div which uses the CSS properties you gave us in your original message.

In that div, you add divs (or spans, or p, whatever element) and the Div will automatically scale up to fit his content, yet will still be on the bottom of the page.